# GWT AccessControlException

Tags: gwt, java-native-interface, accesscontrolexception

I'm trying to comunicate with a JNI service in the serverpart of my GWT application. The problem is that I'm getting a

> 'java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied 
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission
>   loadLibrary.HelloWorld)'

Error. I ´Google for the java Security and Permissions model and found a description on http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html

I tried to add the

> grant {   permission
>   java.security.AllPermission; };

to my \workspace.......\war\WEB-INF\deploy.......\rpcPolicyManifest\manifest.txt
but that wasnt the policy manifest file...

In which file do I add premissions or how do I tell at compiletime what premissions he uses.

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (well part of it)

To run code which needs extra premissions you have to use AccessController.doPrivileged(...)

See:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html